# Not able to enter and edit values in edit text android list view

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-edittext

> Am new to list view in android , i want to enter different values manually in edit text in list view but am but able to achieve it , any body guide me to achieve it

```
package com.example.limitscale.beautylog;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GiftAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
CheckBox check;
//boolean[] checkBoxState;
private int editingPosition = 0;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
EditText quantity1;
int temp;
int q=0;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyAppSharedPrefs";
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public GiftAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    //  checkBoxState=new boolean[arraylist.size()];
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}
private class ViewHolder
{
    CheckBox check;
    EditText quantity1;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    temp=position;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.giftadapter, parent, false);

    viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

    resultp = data.get(position);

    final TextView country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product);
    final  TextView population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    quantity1 = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    quantity1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String charText = quantity1.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    final  ImageView flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    final LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
    ImageButton add_ = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_01);

    final String quan = quantity1.getText().toString();
    country.setText(resultp.get(Giftafriend.COUNTRY));
    population.setText(resultp.get(Giftafriend.POPULATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(Giftafriend.FLAG), flag);

    add_.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            content.setBackgroundColor(0xFFEDD3F6);

            resultp = data.get(position);
            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("addservice", resultp.get(Giftafriend.COUNTRY));
            editor.putString("addprice", resultp.get(Giftafriend.POPULATION));
            editor.commit();
            ((MainActivity) context).showAdd1((resultp.get(position)));

        }
    });

    return itemView;
}}
```

[image]

> I want my output like this but my edit text is not allowing me to change the values in it. its displaying the value 0 that is a hint i have given in my xml.

**gift adapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
android:id="@+id/listrow">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/image" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/product"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Title"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Rs"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:hint="price"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="0"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boxborder"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ad_01"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/cart"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml code of list item

Comment: make your edit text request focus on list item click

Comment: No use of it @vivek , is there any other way to make it work

Comment: you can use to EditorAdapter for this purpose.

Comment: can you show how you tried that

Comment: I added full code , may i know what else you need @vivek. I want to change the value of edittext to change manually that all i need but still am not getting it

Comment: did u solved if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from your adapter item layout.

Comment: It's working for me. Could you please add android:textCursorDrawable="@null" with EditText and see whether cursor is visible or not. Also remove android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" too.

Comment: I found something using log.d command inside the textwatcher that the addTextChangedListener functionality is not working when am clicking on the edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Pls make android:**strong text**editable=true to your edit text

```
   <EditText
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="0"
            **android:editable="true"**
            android:textColor="#eaedfe" />
```